# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Conditionally writing inline text within a tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this tag in my menu

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

and I was wanting to insert a **class="selected"** if the current controller was the HomeController.  So I modified the tag to look like this.

```
<li><a href="/" @if (ViewContext.Controller.ToString().EndsWith("HomeController")) { Response.Write("class=\"selected\""); }>Home</a></li>
```

Now, I see the **class=`&quot;`selected`&quot;`** appear at the top of the page and the rest of the markup is messed up.  I just wanted to have the tag look like this

```
<li><a href="/" class="selected">Home</a></li>
```

If the current controller is the HomeController.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="/" @if (ViewContext.Controller.ToString().EndsWith("HomeController")) { <text>class="selected"</text> }>Home</a>
```

Razor encodes everything by default, if you use the special tag `<text>` it renders the content as is.

Here is a quick reference guide on Razor syntax: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `<text>` tag; it does not prevent HTML encoding.

Comment: @SLaks According to [link](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) there is a note saying: "When you output text as shown in this section — using an HTML element, the @: operator, or the <text> element — ASP.NET doesn't HTML-encode the output.[...]"

Comment: That's because it's literal text; literal text is never encoded.  `@` blocks inside of it are still encoded.